# How to connect to a postgres database in ubuntu

Tags: php, postgresql, ubuntu

I've inherited an ubuntu server with some php pages.

One of those pages has the following code:

```
 // Connessione al db
         $c_res = @pg_connect("", "", "", "", "timesheet");
         if ($c_res == 0)
            header_chiusura ("Errore nel collegamento all'origine dati<br>");

         // Impostazione stile variabili data
         $s_res = @pg_exec ($c_res, "SET DATESTYLE TO 'European'");
         if ($s_res == 0)
            header_chiusura ("Errore nell'esecuzione dell'istruzione SET<br>");

         // Lettura record utente e controlli vari
         if ($arg_nome_utente != "NULL" && $arg_password_utente != "NULL")
            $s_res = @pg_exec ($c_res, "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE nome_utente = '" . $arg_nome_utente . "'");
         else
            $s_res = @pg_exec ($c_res, "SELECT * FROM utenti WHERE id_utente = " . $arg_id_utente);

         if ($s_res == 0)
            header_chiusura ("Errore nell'esecuzione dell'istruzione SELECT<br>");
         $rowcount = @pg_NumRows($s_res);
         if ($rowcount == 0)
            header_chiusura ("Utente non trovato<br>");
         if ($rowcount != 0 && $rowcount != 1)
            header_chiusura ("Errore, chiave duplicata nella tabella utenti<br>");
         $row = @pg_fetch_array($s_res,0);
         $f_id_utente = $row["id_utente"];
         $f_nome_utente = $row["nome_utente"];
         $f_password_utente = $row["password_utente"];
         $f_nome_completo = $row["nome_completo"];
         $f_id_connessione = $row["id_connessione"];
```

Reading that code I assume that there is a  PostgreSQL database located in that machine, and that the database is called "timesheet".
I would like to open that database in an editor. but if I give the following command:

```
root@ubuserver:~# psql timesheet

psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

so I'm asking if there is a way, being root in the machine, to access that database and read what is inside of it.

Comment: Because when you do not specify user for connection psql takes current OS user - so it tried to use "root". You need to specify user name like "psql -U username -d timesheet" (-d stands for database) - psql will most likely ask for password or you can specify login credentials in ~/.pgpass file - please see in documentation.

Comment: @JosMac thank you for your comment, it is very illuminating. but if I give "find / -name .pgpass
" i can't find such file in all the system. How could I access that database without knowing username and password and simply being root?

Comment: @Malkavian The php code must run as some user, you could try that.  Otherwise, the postgres user is likely to work, unless it was specifically disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default with PostgreSQL on Ubuntu is to have a `postgres` Unix user with a corresponding `postgres` database user that can connect to any database and is also a database superuser.

Assuming the defaults, you can basically go from user root to user postgres with `su - postgres`, and then `psql timesheet` should start an SQL session with the database user `postgres` on the database `timesheet`, without asking for a password.

Comment: thank you,root@ubuserver:~# su postgres
postgres@ubuserver:/root$ psql timesheet
Welcome to psql 8.3.9, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
       \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help with psql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit

timesheet=#